# Handshake entre aplicación y servidor

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache

No encontré palabras para poner al título, les explico.

Tengo una aplicación web que utilizamos en la empresa, la tengo programada en el evento `OnBlur` para que vaya a la base de datos y guarde la información que se ingresó.

Desafortunadamente el día de hoy se fue la luz en el servidor y no entró tan rápido la planta y se apagó. Pero nadie se dió cuenta pues la página seguía funcionando. (En RAM)
Una persona le dió F5 a su máquina y por obvias razones no guardó su proceso, ya implementé que la gente triggeree el evento `OnBlur` en todos los campos, para que dicha información se guarde.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna función que, cuando el servidor se apague, marque error en la parte operativa y no les permita continuar, algo como lifeping cada minuto entre el `back-end` y el `front-end`

Uso `Jquery`, `AJAX` y `Bootstrap` del lado del cliente. 
`PHP` y `Apache` del lado del servidor.

Agradezco sus sugerencias y apoyo.

Comment: ¿Estás diciendo que estás guardando datos sin que el usuario confirme que son válidos? ¿Y que ahora, para "arreglarlo", estás guardando datos de formularios incompletos? No me parece la IU más intuitiva del mundo. Y en cuanto a solución, no es necesario pings ni nada... cuando el usuario le de a guardar (sea el método que sea), analiza la respuesta para ver si ha habido un error (¿de qué te sirve hacer un ping que te diga que el servidor funciona si luego lo que está caido es la base de datos o hay un problema de SQL?)

Comment: La operación debe ser lo más rápida posible, ¿Para que quiero mandarle un alert "Se guardo correctamente" si lo que quieren es agilizar la operación? creo que tu opinión de la UI es obsoleta cuando desconoces los mecanismos operativos requeridos. Tu respuesta no se acercó nada a lo que pregunté. Igual, gracias por tu punto de vista.

Answer (score 0):

Has visto `LocalStorage` de `HTML5`? Eso podría ser una 'alternativa' para mantener la data guardada localmente en el navegador para luego ser enviada al servidor.

Con lo que publicas, veo un potencial problema de consistencia de datos... Por otro lado, lo que podrías hacer es un `AJAX` cada minuto con un set interval que genere un `GET` de un recurso por ejemplo una imagen. Si el recurso marca error (porque el server se apagó) entonces que deshabilite el botón siguiente/enviar o cualquier otro que impida continuar con su trabajo.